# EF Core Database First HasNoKey

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a database table created 20 years ago in my company, it is only used for journaling, with NO PRIMARY KEY or INDEX. I can't alter that table.

I understood that we need to call **HasNoKey()** in code first approach.

But how can I apply HasNoKey in this case? Since it is a Database First approach.

Comment: You can check this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your `DbContext` class' `OnModelCreating` method, you do something like this:

```cs
modelBuilder
    .Entity<MyEntity>(builder =>
    {
        builder.HasNoKey();
        builder.ToTable("MY_ENTITY");
    });
```

Read more about it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=fluent-api

Comment: No code first approach. The Database was created 20 years ago.

Comment: @sk This should still apply to DB first ... DB first IS code first, it's just that we generate the Entity Types from the DB first, but it should still create a DbContext with a ConfigureModel method in to which we tell the model that this is going on in the DB.

Comment: I can't resolve .HasNoKey() on my newly created entity.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations

Answer (score 4):

Use **[Keyless]** Attribute of model class.

Comment: Simpler solution!!!

Comment: Which using do you used?